# Why is the hex color in my PNG different from the same hex code in browser?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, css, hex, browser

Here is an issue which I can't seem to solve: I have a PNG image with a small blue triangle. It's an asset used for a website that I'm creating with a developer. The appearance of its blue is a bit off, just very slightly different from the same hex color that is put on items through CSS.

When inspecting the PNG in photoshop, sampling the blue gives me the exact same hex code as what is used in CSS, yet they look different while both viewing them in a browser. How come?

I should note I have a calibrated monitor and manage colors, but a hex code is a hex code, no matter what profile you're on. Switching profiles should not influence the hex code.

Comment: Different color settings

Comment: A hex code is not the same no matter what profile you're on, that's exactly what a profile does—tell you what that hex code means.

Comment: Well, that is exactly what I meant; what you see might be different on different screens, but the code remains the same. Now why does my screen show a different color for the same hex in CSS than what Photoshop shows me? Photoshop just uses my general color profile.

Comment: is that profile sRGB IEC 61966-2-1? If it isn't then that hex code corresponds to a different color.

Comment: Hi RaymonV, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: My photoshop color settings are  sRGB IEC61966-2.1 and color management policy is to preserve embedded profiles

My screen calibration is not set to that profile ofcourse (would not show proper colors), but when switching to that profile and turning off preserve embedded profiles, the file still gives me the same hex for the blue

Comment: Could you post the image?

Comment: Here it is, the blue is supposed to be #1c314c. I should also note the color difference is more obvious on my windows machine than on my Mac, and my Windows screen isn't calibrated.
http://raymonvanvught.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/popup_item_arrow.png

Comment: Well, it works perfectly ok for me so I'm not sure what the issue is... could you link to a somewhere where you see the issue?

Comment: I can't share the site it's hosted on, still under embargo, but here's a screenshot I've taken from the image in context on my Windows machine. You can clearly see the triangle having a different hue.
http://raymonvanvught.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/color-diff.png

Comment: By the way, I did a round and looked on some of my colleague's screens (we have different screens) and it looks alright on theirs. Now that leads me to the conclusion that it's highly likely that my Windows PC screen is the culprit. Now I still really wonder what makes that one screen act that way...

Answer (score 3):

This can happen in combinations of following reasons:

- Profile in OS's Color Management.
- Profile in Photoshop's Color Settings.
- Profile included in your image.

Your problem looks like your image has same profile as Photoshop but differs from OS's profile.

So your CSS color and image color are exactly same but CSS’s color showed using OS’s color profile and image showed using included profile. As a result, you see different colors because of different conversion made by different profiles.

Try to open your image in Photoshop and then re-save using Save for Web, make sure “Embed Color Profile” option unchecked, then watch again in browser.

When working for web (screens), to avoid color problems:

- Set same color profiles in Windows and Photoshop (sRGB would be best choice).
- Don’t include (embed) color profiles in images.
- Adjust what you want to see in Monitor settings and not through profiles or graphic card driver.